# Session replication issue between instances on Glassfish

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, replication, weld

I try to use session replication between 2 local instances (on same cluster, same node), using glassfish 4.

I followed some tutorials and added following input in my web.xml file : 
I also checked "availability" enabled when deploying war file on my target (the cluster).

My application is based on Spring + JSF2 (@ManagedBeans from javax.faces.bean).
(Mojarra 2.2.4, which I also override from original javax.faces.jar in the GF/modules directory).

No weld, no jboss, no conversation.

Everything works fine when deployed on glassfish admin server, even when deployed on a single instance (other instance shut down). It also works with the 2 instances when I disable 'Availability' when deploying the war file.

But when trying to use native session replication behavior I get following trace and my application doesn't display (or even the instance crashes).

It seems to be a session deserialization issue.

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>Same issue either with 'server' or 'client'</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I get following issue :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator to field org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.advisorChainFactory of type org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisorChainFactory in instance of org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2083)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1995)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2078)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1986)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1272)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StoreBase.readSession(StoreBase.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.getSession(ReplicationStore.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.getSession(ReplicationStore.java:519)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.loadFromBackingStore(ReplicationStore.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.load(ReplicationStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.doSwapIn(PersistentManagerBase.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.swapIn(PersistentManagerBase.java:1175)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationManagerBase.findSession(ReplicationManagerBase.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:3218)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSessionInternal(Request.java:3081)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.unlockSession(Request.java:4665)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I really don't know why as I'm not using neither JBOSS nor any conversation behavior (or annotation).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

I had issues with session serialization and deserialization, because I had @ManagedProperty attached to Spring AOP.

It had nothing to do with this jboss weld stack trace (which I don't get anymore, but I still can't guess what this stack trace had to do with the core of the issue).